# In VSTS, how to view multiple backlogs at once?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

I have multiple projects that me and my development team are working on at the same time.
I have all teams projects task backlogs at 
https://{vstsName}.visualstudio.com/{projectOne}/_backlogs/iteration/Iteration%201
https://{vstsName}.visualstudio.com/{projectTwo}/_backlogs/iteration/Iteration%201

I want to see every backlog at once and can't find a way to view them all at once.
I have tried the Delivery Plans plug in, but this didn't seem to give what I want.
I want to view all tasks and be able to make them active, and possible to see all burn downs at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "Work > Queries > New > New Query" there is a checkbox in the top right of the query editor called "Query across projects". If you check this checkbox then work items from all projects will be included in the query results.

Comment: Cheers for that, Odd that the query is on a project, but we can live with that.